# Looping over a condition defined as argument

Tags: python, arguments

I would like to define a function that returns something if a condition is True. But I want to pass the condition as argument of the function!

```
def foo(condition):
   i=0
   while True:
      if condition==True:
         print i
      i+=1
```

For example with this example function, how can I pass an argument to have condition = (i%2==0)? (I want to be able to use internal function variables in the condition)

The reason I want to achieve this is to write a generic class sending informations to other function depending on various conditions.

Comment: Use a lambda or a function as the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you can pass a function as an argument. Taking your example, you could do something like this:

```
def foo(condition):
   i=0
   while i < 10:
      if condition(i):
         print i
      i+=1

def is_even(x):
    return (x % 2) == 0

foo(is_even)
```